# PHP - pass PDO connection to all functions

Tags: php, pdo

I have a try catch block that connects via PDO to a database. I would like to be able to reference it in all my functions without having to pass it as a parameter. How would I do this? The mentioned code is:

```
try {
    $database = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=coop1','root','');
    $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getmessage();
    die();
}
```

EDIT:

I created a singleton class (attempt below) that executes the try catch block upon `_construct`

```
final class database {

    private static $instance = NULL;


    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $database = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=coop1','root','');
            $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getmessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        static $instance = null;
        if (self::$instance === NULL) {
            $instance = new database();
        }
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global)

Comment: i would not make a global. Class are meant to be portable unit of code. What will happen if you use the class without having those global set outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare it as a static attribute of a singleten class. Than you can access it with

```
$pdo = Singleton::instance()->getConnection();
```

Alternatively I can suggest taking a look at MArtin Fowler's relational database mapping pattern. It goes a step further, than centralizing ony the connection itself.

Alternatively Doctirne project has a complete implementation of that: www.doctrine-project.org

```
final class database {

    private static $instance = NULL;

    private $pdo;  //added private variable for pdo


    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $database = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=coop1','root','');
            $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getmessage();
            die();
        }

        $this->pdo = $database; //saved the connection into the new variable
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        static $instance = null;
        if (self::$instance === NULL) {
            $instance = new database();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    //added a function to get the connection itself
    function getConnection(){
        return $this->pdo;
    }
}
```

So now you use it:

```
$pdo = database::getInstance()->getConnection();
```

Comment: I created the singleton block (see edited post), and created an instance: `$db = database::getInstance();`, but when I reference `$db` in a function it isnt recognized in the scope still. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are returning the reference to the singleton class itselsf (the instance variable), not the connection. just a sec, I'll add an edit too.

Comment: right! because I have to return what specifically in that instance I need, which is in this case the PDO. Thanks :)

Comment: is there a quick way to get it to where i don't have to use `$pdo = database::getInstance()->getConnection();` in every function? I read that using it as a global is bad practice

Comment: You have some confusion regarding the terminology. None of this is global. It is a container class for your connection. If you want the best available solution, get a get a copy of Apress.-.PHP.Objects.Patterns.and.Practice.3rd.Edition.2010 and take a look at the database pattern. Lot of head scratching really hard first times I guess, but according to my best knowledge that is the best pattern you can use (Martin Fowler's realtional database mapping)

Comment: oh  ya i didn't mean imply that it was global. Repharasing - The answer you give works well and I will use it. Ideally though I would like to make the connection accessible whereever without having to define it, such as placing it in a global (but i hear this is bad practice)

Comment: You can use it as a global. Reason why using globals is considered a bad practice is that they are easy to overwrite and as a project continues to grow you would need more and more globals. Easy to make mistakes. I ususally use globals only for config settings (if you ever used joomla, the base joomla config is built up of globals). So you can not just simply declare it as being good or bad, but usually  in long term if you are planning on continuous development it pays off to encapsulate code particles into classes. Well the book I refered to is a great (not easy)read, maybe take a look at it

Comment: Clarification needed after reading this: is `$pdo = database::getInstance()->getConnection();` the same PDO instance or a copy of the singleton's property?  For instance, if I run two functions back-to-back in the same script, each beginning with that statement, will it produce problems because they're using two separate PDO instances?  Or are they both pointing to the `database` class?